# Spring Boot / Oracle / Java error : Could not get JDBC Connection results in Connection timed out

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

The system I am working with has the following (I am using Spring Boot)

I am getting an error when starting an application using the following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: `Could not get JDBC Connection`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: `The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

because of this, I get a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

Below is other information.

Why am I getting this error? The code sees the connection.url - but - it says that it can't work with it. As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct. How can I fix this?

TIA

**the pom.xml file**

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ccinrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>BackEndRestFunctionality</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootErrorHandlingDemoy</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            $NO-MVN-MAN-VER$
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The **application.properties** file looks like the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/DSV
spring.datasource.username=<my_id>
spring.datasource.password=<my_password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery="SELECT 1"

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database
# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
#hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

**Error Log**

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2018-01-24 19:25:06.507  INFO 12076 --- [           main] ccinrest.App                             : Starting App on DESKTOP-8EFRPQF with PID 12076 (C:\WORK\Test\SpringBootErrorHandlingDemo\target\classes started by dgmufasa in C:\WORK\Test\SpringBootErrorHandlingDemo)
2018-01-24 19:25:06.511  INFO 12076 --- [           main] ccinrest.App                             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-24 19:25:06.629  INFO 12076 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64d7f7e0: startup date [Wed Jan 24 19:25:06 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-24 19:25:09.949  INFO 12076 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-24 19:25:09.968  INFO 12076 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-01-24 19:25:09.973  INFO 12076 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2018-01-24 19:25:10.183  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-24 19:25:10.183  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3559 ms
2018-01-24 19:25:10.523  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-24 19:25:10.524  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-24 19:25:10.524  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-24 19:25:10.524  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-24 19:25:10.526  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-01-24 19:25:10.526  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-24 19:25:33.725 ERROR 12076 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]

[.. snip ...]

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:81) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:169) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Comment: _"The code sees the connection.url - but - it says that it can't work with it"_ -- Not quite. The error is saying that the DB server process did not respond to the connection. Is the database server started? Is it listening on port 1521?  What happens if you `telnet localhost 1521`?

Comment: Perhaps the process of the listener does not listen to the `localhost`, but listens to another IP address. Check the compatibility between your jdbc ojdbc8 12.2.0.1 driver and the database.What is version Oracle database?

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. What it was was that I was using an external IP address for the machine. I think the firewall is on now. I changed it to an internal IP address 192.168.x.x and it all worked. :-) So, in the end, it was with the use of the hostname.